# After Merging Tiff Files the merged file is black and gray

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, multi-band

I have 24 Tiff Rasters which I want to combine into one TIFF file but when I merge them the color of the new TIFF is black and gray.  The render type of the new TIFF is singleband gray but if I change it then it turns funky colors and does not look correct.

I merge by going to processing > toolbox > GDAL/OGR merge

[image]

Comment: You mean from the python console?  Should I write a script with what you commented with named " gdal_merge.py "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do it from command line.
Here's an example of how to merge R,G,B into a multiband raster:

```
# create virtual multi-band raster 
gdalbuildvrt -separate rgb.vrt red.tif green.tif blue.tif
# write multi-band raster into geotiff
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB rgb.vrt rgb.tif
```

Comment: gdal_translate -of GTiff -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB rgb.vrt rgb.tif
  File "<input>", line 1
    gdal_translate -of GTiff -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB rgb.vrt rgb.tif
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  >>>This comes up as the syntax error

Comment: please run command from terminal, not python console

Comment: As in an external program not in QGIS?  Sorry, I don't code much.  Unsure on where the terminal is located.

Answer (score 0):

Within the QGIS GUI for GDAL functions, you can edit the command so it looks like the line for the "terminal" and then run the GDAL function.  By terminal, that means the command prompt in Windows.